# Try-Catch statement on video.muted doesn't caught any error on Chrome

Tags: javascript, video, try-catch

I wanted to have a function that unmute a video.

As far as I know, Chrome blocks unmute video if the user isn't focused on the webpage. I wanted to have a callback whenever this happen, because it pauses the video. (in fact, I would like to keep it mute and continue the playing)

I tried to use a try-catch statement but it doesn't caught the warning error :

```
      try {
            video.muted = false;
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log("warning:" + e)
            chromeHasBlockedTheUnmute();
        }
```

As you can tell chrome doesn't catch the warning

[image: try catch]

Thanks in advance